# How to add column in the beginning of file using perl?

Tags: shell, sed, awk, perl

I want a Perl one-liner that checks whether the first fields of an input file is the file's name and, if it isn't, adds the file name as the first column on every line.

**Example written in shell :**

```
for f in *file*.csv;
do 
  file_column=`cat ${f} | awk -F',' '{print$1}'`
  if [ $file_column != ${f} ]
  then
    sed -i "s/^/$f,/" $f 2>/dev/null;
  fi 
done
```

But the approach above, which checks whether the file name is present in the first column and adds it if it isn't, is taking ~3 Hours for 4 Laks files. I understand that Perl is faster for file operations.

**The Perl command I tried:**

```
perl -p -i -e 's/^/Welcome to Hell,/' file*.csv
```

Please help me add the logic to check whether the field exists already and only change if it doesn't.

```
Input : file1.csv 
col1,col2,col3 
data1,data2,dat3 

Output: file1.csv 
file1.csv,col1,col2,col3 
file1.csv,data1,data2,data3
```

or if here is any faster way please suggest. Perl one liner because it's part of another shell script so tiny call will be better i guess (suggest please)

Comment: Can you give some sample input/output? Also: Why is a one liner desirable?

Comment: I would offer - embedding perl into another script isn't as useful as just writing a script in perl.

Comment: @Sobrique ,  i would be happy if you offer an perl script for the above problem

Answer (score 3):

Here's your perl one-liner: it works with multiple file arguments

```
perl -i -pe '/^$ARGV,/ or print "$ARGV,"' file1 file2 ...
```

`$ARGV` is the magic variable that holds the filename of the current file.
See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles

The field separator (comma) is hardcoded. You can decide if that's a problem.

Small performance improvement:

```
perl -i -pe 'index($_, "$ARGV,") == 0 or print "$ARGV,"' file1 file2 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Before told about perl speed try to speed up your own script

```
for f in *file*.csv;
do 
    sed -i "/^$f,/! s/^/$f,/" "$f"
done
```

Comment: other than first line it removed rest of the line in the file ,i need file name along with the data as starting column

Comment: @WilliamR I have edited already

Comment: Thanks lot @Costas  , It took 20 seconds for 30K file, Let me check for 4Laks files.

Comment: It's taking long time to complete for 4 Laks files , For smaller amount like 30K files it's taking ~5 to 10 seconds. Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

While you can actually do this with Perl, the syntax is not the simplest (or at least, it isn't with the best I can come up with). It will probably be both simpler and faster to use other tools. For example,

1. [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211797/22222)
2. gawk (relatively recent versions)

   ```
   for f in file*csv; do  
       awk -i inplace -F, '{
                             if($1==FILENAME){print} else{print FILENAME","$0}
                           }' "$f"; 
   done
   ```

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem with a 'perl one liner' as you note:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/^/Welcome to Hell,/' file*.csv
```

This applies a transform to the file right enough, but perl 'handles' opening the file(s) and streaming them through `STDIN` automagically. Which means you don't know your file name when you're doing it.

The `in place edit` option (`-i`) is a convenience but actually becomes rather more difficult to actually use effectively, since you're potentially opening a file for reading and writing concurrently.

Anyway, I'd approach your problem like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );

foreach my $filename ( glob("*.csv") ) {
    open( my $output, ">", "new.$filename.csv" ) or warn $!;
    open( my $input, "<", "$filename.csv" ) or warn $!;
    while ( my $row = $csv->getline($input) ) {
        if ( not $row->[0] eq m/$filename/ ) {
            unshift( @{$row}, $filename );
        }
        $csv->print( $output, $row );
    }
}
```

It uses the `Text::CSV` module, because actually CSV is often more complicated than just "split on comma" (think multi-line fields, and commas in text).

Answer (score 1):

Can't manage a one liner, but here's a **perl** script. Put it in a file
and make it executable. Then give it the `*.csv` filenames as args. It
creates `*.new` files. If you are confident it works, uncomment the
`rename` command at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
foreach my $file(@ARGV){
    open(F,$file) or die "$file:$!";
    $_ = <F>;
    next if $_=~/^$file,/;
    open(OUT,">$file.new") or die;
    my $add = "$file,";
    print OUT $add,$_;
    while(<F>){
        print OUT $add,$_;
    }
    close OUT;
    close F;
    #rename("$file.new","$file");
}
```